# Felix File Install OSGi: How to automatically load a bundle (Configuration and how it works)?

Tags: file, load, osgi, apache-felix

I was looking for a way to load and start OSGi Bundles on the fly during runtime into my system. However after finding Felix File Install, I thought this is problably the most elegant and easy working way.
Thing is: It's not working. ;-)
I downloaded the Felix File Install Jar and deployd it as an OSGi Bundle into my software.
It also starts with all my OSGi Bundles in Eclipse without any problems. However, I don't know where I should set the properties file (Tried to put them in the arguments box at eclipse's project properties. no success though).
Furthermore my Bundle isn't reacting when something in the directory is changing. Even when creating the default directory and manipulating its content, nothing happens. No Bundles get loaded. Somehow I have the feeling I have overseen something huge here, since it seems to work for most people just perfect with not that mch effort?

Would be really glad for your help.

Bye

NOTE: There is no Apache Felix installed. Only the felix file install jar. The OSGi is running on equinox...

Comment: Any additional information? What is the output of your logs or bundle list? Are you starting equinox embedded in a custom application, embedded in eclipse, or standalone?

Comment: No error or anything. the bundle lists shows all bundles excet the one that should loaded. I would be really thankful if somebody could provide a step by step explanation, since I never used felix file install before. Seems to me as there is a simple setting i forgot to set, since nothing happens at all and no exception is thrown.

Comment: I'll post an example of me having gotten it, but please add more info! What folder are you adding it to? What do you have in that folder? Stuff like that. I can post my working proof of concept but I doubt it'll help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are system properties not program arguments for equinox. Use it like this :

```
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/pickup
```

As per their [documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html) the default value for this is `./load`.

NOTE: In eclipse add the above in the VM arguments

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The same info that I have found in the internet but couldn't get iot work with that. Where does this default folder have to be? In my Felix Bundle? Where could I put it and how can I find the right path to it.